# Gerrit accessible from the IP address but not from the canonical URL

Tags: debian, java, debian-lenny, jetty

I just installed `Gerrit` on my Debian server (Linode) and can't get the canonical URL to work.

Relevant log information (anonymized):

```
[2010-09-13 17:48:06,550] INFO  com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon : Started Gerrit SSHD on apollo.MYURL.com:29418
[2010-09-13 17:48:06,550] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log : jetty-7.0.2.v20100331
[2010-09-13 17:48:07,023] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log : Started SelectChannelConnector@XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8180
[2010-09-13 17:48:07,029] INFO  com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Gerrit Code Review 2.1.5 ready
```

During Gerrit's init, here's the relevant information from the `SSH` terminal:

```
*** SSH Daemon
*** 

Listen on address              [XXX.XXX.XXX.XX]: 
Listen on port                 [29418]: 

*** HTTP Daemon
*** 

Behind reverse proxy           [y/N]? 
Use SSL (https://)             [y/N]? 
Listen on address              [XXX.XXX.XXX.XX]: 
Listen on port                 [8180]: 
Canonical URL                  [http://review.MYURL.com:8180/]:
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doi. I had not yet set up the `A` record for the subdomain. Simple answer for a seemingly complex question.